# Breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy when an alert should be shown on WKInterfaceController

Tags: alert, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

My watch app uses a `WKInterfaceController` to display a `WKInterfaceTable`. In case of errors, it displays an alert using `presentAlert` called in the presented `WKInterfaceController`.
I have set a symbolic breakpoint at `UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy`, because I got earlier the warning:

> Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells
>   and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view
>   or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may
>   cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform
>   layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait
>   collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also
>   cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes.
>   Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the
>   debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this
>   action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has
>   been added to a window.

Now my app stops at this breakpoint when my `WKInterfaceTable` is displayed, and an alert should be presented, at

```
let visibleInterfaceController = WKExtension.shared().visibleInterfaceController
visibleInterfaceController?.presentAlert(withTitle: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [okAction])
```

The stack trace is:
[image]

My question is:
What is the reason for this breakpoint, and how can it be avoided?

EDIT:
I just realised that when I try to edit this breakpoint, it shows:
[image]
...and I have no idea what it means...